# How Do I Fill This Bowl With Balls?

Tags: particles, rigidbody

I have a rigid body setup but I can't figure out why my particle objects won't fill the bowl.

I have rigid body set for the both the ball object (active) and the bowl (passive), scales are applied, but the particles just keep dropping without interacting with the bowl.

What am I doing wrong?

[Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7yg4gmpsp47y8t/Fill%20Bowl%20With%20Balls.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: you cannot. Particles do not collide with themselves. So you should use rigid bodies.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I should have known that. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, there is no particle collision. But you can fake it.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvcVX.gif Turning the bowl over so that everything falls out might be a bit tricky.